# Edit account privilige in apex

Tags: oracle-apex

i can't edit users privileges in apex as below image, it show read only.
[account screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCckG.png)

the privileges are:

- User is a developer
- Application Builder Access
- SQL Workshop Access
- Team Development Access

Answer (score 0):

The user in question is an administrator, which includes all of the other privileges already. There's nothing more to assign, and you can't assign the other privileges individually unless you take away the administrator privilege first.

Comment: not just this user, but all users in apex like him. for example i want to make (team development access - NO), i can't make it.

Comment: You have to make them developers. Set "Administrator" to "No". Alternatively you could go to the Internal workspace and disable team development for your entire development workspace - all users (including you) with no exceptions.